# UK Standard Visit Visa

Tags: uk, tourist-visas

I am a non-EU student studying in Barcelona and have a valid residence permit of Spain. Currently, I am in Venice as an exchange student and I want to apply for UK Standard Tourist Visit Visa.

Can apply for UK Standard Tourist Visit visa from their authorities in Italy, instead of going to Spain & applying?

I couldn't find any information on the UK website about this.

Comment: I was sure that this is a duplicate, but can't find anything.

Comment: Yes, you can apply in Italy, or any other country that has a UK mission.